# Can't choose an answer

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, answers

I can't choose an answer to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914470).

[image]

I'm getting the same issue on the full version:

[image]

I am shown that error for more than eight minutes now. How do I fix this?

**Edit:** I still need an answer to this problem, I had to pick an answer yesterday, but it wouldn't let me and said that I have to wait **2** minutes instead of 8. As you can see, I've set up a bounty.

**Edit #2:** This is happening to me for the 3rd time. This time, it's 44 seconds.
[image]

Comment: The comments were going off the rails a bit here. @Vlad, thanks for the bug report. We will look into it soon as we can.

Comment: See you chose answer shortly after posting this report. @Anna was there really a bug here?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd As was contained within the now removed comments, the OP claimed that the chosen answer was the only one he could accept. The other answers wouldn't let him.

Comment: Seems a shame that the comments were removed. This is my first time on this question and it seems like I've missed out on _all_ the context. Permanently.

Comment: I was able to pick the answer yesterday. It's some time bug.

Comment: @Lightness nothing is permanent... become a mod and all comments will be revealed to you, deleted or not. :)

Comment: @Vlad1k any chance the time settings on your device were off? Those things might depend on the local time.

Comment: I am on am on my iPod. I wasn't able to set the answer I wanted for 2 days, but magically I was able to set it on a third one.

Comment: This hasn't been reproduced by anyone so far, so perhaps it is premature to set a bounty claiming that this is applicable to a wide audience.

Comment: In the (now deleted) comments, some users complained about this too. **I am experiencing this AGAIN with 44 seconds. This is highly annoying.**

Comment: @Vlad1k Are you experiencing this on all SE sites or just a particular one?

Comment: I am only using Stack Overflow. This is horrible. I hope I am not the only one who is having this issue.

Comment: Any chance you can better describe this issue by editing your question? It's really hard to understand exactly what is going wrong here, and whether you've tried other browsers.

Comment: As you can see I am using Safari on my iPod. It's not a problem on my part. I have used a full site on my iPod and used my laptop, and still no luck. This is most likely a server side issue.

Comment: How could you have experienced this problem so recently when you've been suspended for all of today? Suspended users cannot accept answers.

Comment: If you read my second edit you would notice that I wasn't able to pick it on meta. I am not suspended from meta.

Comment: Oh right, didn't spot that. This is why I was asking you what site you are experiencing this on. Your answer was: "I am only using Stack Overflow".

Comment: http://meta.STACKOVERFLOW.com/

Comment: Dunno why I got -2 votes.

Comment: I was able to choose the second answer. The first one is stuck on 44 seconds...

Comment: I noticed. Does the message fade and reappear every time you click on the accept check mark (for the one you can't accept)?

Comment: It's not about the effects, its just that whatever I do (refresh/change browsers/change computers/wait 1 hour) it still doesn't let me. I was able to choose the answer I **wanted** in 3 days which is weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oy, another iOS 6 bug.

Safari's caching is basically wrong now (leading to Safari giving you the same error message everytime, even though you only talk to our servers *once*), I've deployed an attempt at a work around.

Let me know if it's still broken.

Comment: I have tried using a computer, still same thing.